# Laravel Elixir not watching SASS import files for gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir

I have elixir set up to watch changes in .scss files, but changes in _partials.scss are not being watched.

```
elixir(function(mix){

   mix.browserSync([

      'resources/assets/bower/bootstrap-sass/assets/**/*'   

   ], {

     proxy: 'site.app',
     reloadDelay: 200

   });

});
```

When I edit the bootstrap/_variables.scss, gulp does compile those sass changes. If I exit gulp watch, and gulp watch again, then those changes appear.

So I know its compiling correctly, its just somehow not watching those partial files.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is already in a pull request on the repo. (https://github.com/laravel/elixir/pull/377)

Until fixed, I'm gonna apply the same fix for now as Ricardo (see https://github.com/ricardogobbosouza/elixir/commit/948abb930e0d822a6fa6a8531d52a8d51632c59b)