# Laravel Elixir watch all imported .scss files

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I want to watch everything that's connected to my `app.scss` file, so whenever i run `gulp watch` in my root directory, i wan't it to detect changes in imported paths aswell as in `app.scss`.

This is `app.scss`

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";


.title {
  font-size: 96px;
}
```

my `.gulpfile` look like this

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('./elixir-extensions');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass([
        'app.scss'
    ], 'public/assets/css');

    mix.scripts([
        '../../bower/0/index.js',
        '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
        'app.js'
    ], 'public/assets/js');

    mix.version(['assets/css/app.css', 'assets/js/all.js']);
});
```

As you can see i tried with elixir extension, but no results.

Comment: Why not just add them to the `mix.sass([...])` array?

Comment: does it watch them tho ? or just compiles ? that's what i've been wondering about

Comment: Had the same issue - see [my answer on a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34234226/1554396).

Answer (score 1):

I just added

```
elixir.Task.find('sass')
.watch('resources/assets/js/angular/components/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
```

at the final of the gulpfile.js

And i had to add all the files with .scss extension:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.scss',
        '../js/angular/**/*.style.scss', // My path
    ]);
});
```